# unable to display Search Result using search parameters first name and last name

Tags: jsf-2

Search Parameters are first name and last name while when i click on the search it is getting the value because i m printing then on console but not displaying using datatable. the code that i have written for this purpose is given below:

```
studentSearch.xhtml

 <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
        xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
        xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
        xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core">

    <h:head>
    <title>Search the Student Here</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form id="searchForm">
        <center><b>Search the Student Details Here</b></center>

            <h:panelGrid id="searchStudent" columns="4">
                <h:outputLabel id="searchText" value="Enter the firstname of the Student:"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="searchfName" value="#{student.firstName}"></h:inputText>

                <h:outputLabel id="searchlText" value="Enter the lastname of the Student:"></h:outputLabel>
                <h:inputText id="searchfName" value="#{student.lastName}"></h:inputText>

                <h:commandButton value="Search Student" action="#{student.fullInfoByname}"></h:commandButton>

                <h:dataTable  value="#{searchBean.lstSearch}" var="student">

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Student School ID
                    </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{student.studentSchoolID}"></h:outputText>
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Student First Name
                    </f:facet>
                        #{student.firstName}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Student Last Name
                    </f:facet>
                        #{student.lastName}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Father's Name
                    </f:facet>
                        #{student.fatherName}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Mother's Name
                    </f:facet>
                        #{student.motherName}
                </h:column>

                <h:column>
                    <f:facet name="header">
                        Gender
                    </f:facet>
                        #{student.gender}
                </h:column>

                </h:dataTable>
            </h:panelGrid>


        </h:form>
    </h:body>
    </html>
```

Methods used for this purpose
StudentDao.java method

```
    public List<Student> getStudentByName(String fname,String lname)
        {
            Transaction trans=null;
            Session session=HiberUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
            try{
                trans=session.beginTransaction();
                String queryString="from Student where firstName = :id or lastName = :idd";
                Query query=session.createQuery(queryString);
                query.setString("id", fname);
                query.setString("idd", lname);
                List<Student> list=query.list();

                if(list.size()>0)
                {
                    return list;
                }
            }catch(Exception e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }




    in Student.java class

    public void fullInfoByname()
        {
            StudentDao dao=new StudentDao();
            List<Student> list=new ArrayList<Student>();
            List<Student> lc=dao.getStudentByName(firstName, lastName);
            for(int i=0;i<lc.size();i++)
            {
                System.out.println(lc.get(0).firstName);

                this.studentSchoolID=lc.get(0).studentSchoolID;
                System.out.println(lc.get(0).studentSchoolID);

                this.lastName=lc.get(0).lastName;
                System.out.println(lc.get(0).lastName);

                this.fatherName=lc.get(0).fatherName;
                System.out.println(lc.get(0).fatherName);

                this.motherName=lc.get(0).motherName;
                System.out.println(lc.get(0).motherName);

                this.gender=lc.get(0).gender;
                System.out.println(lc.get(0).gender);
                this.fee=lc.get(0).fee;
                this.course=lc.get(0).course;
                this.session=lc.get(0).session;
                this.hobbies=lc.get(0).hobbies;
                this.email=lc.get(0).email;
                this.phoneNumber=lc.get(0).phoneNumber;
                this.addressOne=lc.get(0).addressOne;
                this.addressTwo=lc.get(0).addressTwo;
                this.city=lc.get(0).city;
                this.state=lc.get(0).state;
                this.zip=lc.get(0).zip;
                this.country=lc.get(0).country;
                this.status=lc.get(0).status;
            }



            list.addAll(lc);
            System.out.println("list Size="+list.size());
            if(list.size()>0)
            {
                SearchStudent sc=new SearchStudent();
                sc.setLstSearch(list);
            }

        }
```

Now in the last i m putting the list sc.setLstSearch after getting it in the xhtml page it is not displaying searched values while if i m getting the size of the variable lstSearch then it is giving correct size but not deisplaying it.
the list created in the searchBean is as follow.

```
    package com.school.entity;

    import java.util.Iterator;
    import java.util.List;

    import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
    import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;

    @ManagedBean(name="searchBean")
    @SessionScoped

    public class SearchStudent {

        private List<Student> lstSearch;

        public List<Student> getLstSearch() {
            return lstSearch;
        }

        public void setLstSearch(List<Student> lstSearch) {
            this.lstSearch = lstSearch;
            //System.out.println(lstSearch);
            //for checking how many values coming from the list
            /*Iterator<Student> itr=lstSearch.iterator();
            while(itr.hasNext())
            {
                System.out.println(itr.next());
            }*/

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in Student class, you should not create SearchStudent class using new operator. Try to inject it using managedProperty and set it. If you don't know how to use it please follow this tutorial http://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/injecting-managed-beans-in-jsf-2-0/

**update:**

After your comment what I noticed is, Student.java is an entity class. Its not good to place business logic in entity class and also injection are not permitted in entity classes. So update your code as follows

1. Move the method `public void fullInfoByname()` to managed bean i.e `SearchStudent` class.
2. Create two properties `firstName` and `lastName` in `SearchStudent` class
3. Set the value of input controls for search to the property of `SearchStudent` class.
4. Change the action method in search form to the method `fullInfoByname` in SearchStudent.
5. After this you can directly call `this.setLstSearch(list);` in `fullInfoByname` method

Comment: @ManagedProperty(value="#{searchBean}")
 private SearchStudent search;
 
 public SearchStudent getSearch() {
  return search;
 }

 public void setSearch(SearchStudent search) {
  this.search = search;
 }

when i used this code in Student.java class.it is giving error of the invalidHibernateColumn mapping Exception.
I m using Annotations in this class.The working is in the same class.

Comment: Ohh so student class is entity class.You cannot use injection in entity classes. Move your fullinfoByName to SearchStudent class and update xhtml accordingly. I will update the answer above

Comment: i moved code for the searchStudent.xhtml to the searchBean.
and then created the variables there and get the values.Now again i m getting the values on Console.but not displayed in the datatable

Comment: @Rohit see the update above and change your code accordingly.

Comment: @Rohit if this has helped you please accept the answer

Comment: thanks for helping me... You have also given the right way but the main problem is in the xhtml file where i m setting var name as student. and my entity class name is also student.that is tha main problem. Thank u very much for help.